# Disable Smooth Scrolling on Non-Anchor Hash Link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some jquery for smooth scrolling:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
    }, 1400);
});
```

Which works fine, except that I have some tabs on the page that use a hash link also. When you click each tab, the page scrolls to the top of the screen.

Is there a way to make this smooth scroll work, only when a specific anchor is added to the hash (like /#features) and not work when it is a hash only (like /#)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a [`:not()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to eliminate `href="#"` from triggering your `click` event.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]:not([href=#])', function(event) {
  console.log("Clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Hash Only</a>
<a href="#Anchor1">Anchor 1</a>
<a href="#Anchor2">Anchor 2</a>
```

Comment: Works in your snippet, though for some reason to preserve the smooth scrolling functionality I needed to add the 'a' before the [href=#] in the :not selector i.e. 

$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]:not(a[href=#])', function(event) {
  console.log("Clicked");
});

Works now. Thanks!